# Is completeness of a financial model relevant for derivatives pricing?

Tags: derivatives, risk-neutral-measure, pricing

If a market model is complete then every derivative has a unique arbitrage free price. However we are not starting with a model but with a arbitrage free Model class $\mathcal{M}$ (E.g. the Blackscholes model family).  Let $\Phi(m)$ be the set of Martingale measures attached to a specfic model $m \in \mathcal{M}$. Completeness (of a model family) then just means  $|\Phi(m)|=1 \forall m \in \mathcal{M}$. We want to price a derivative $\Psi$. for a complete model we have
$$\Pi(\Psi) = \mathbb{E}_{\Phi(m)}[\frac{\Psi}{B_T}]$$
For an incomplete model we have
$$\Pi(\Psi) \in (\inf\limits_{Q \in \Phi(m)}\mathbb{E}_{Q}[\frac{\Psi}{B_T}],\sup\limits_{Q \in \Phi(m)}\mathbb{E}_{Q}[\frac{\Psi}{B_T}])$$

Therefore I thought that one would actually calculate in the incomplete case a price interval in practice and that this would differentiate complete from incomplete models, making the former easier and the latter more robust.

However Usually we calibrate the risk neutral distribution to market prices. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the space of Market data. Let $\mathcal{M}_{rn} = \bigcup\limits_{m\in \mathcal{M}}\Phi(m)$. Calibration is then a map $c_{\mathcal{M}}: \mathcal{D} \to\mathcal{M}_{rn} $.

Therefore for any Model class $\mathcal{M}$ the price of a derivative would be calculated as
$$\Pi(\Psi) = \mathbb{E}_{c_{\mathcal{M}}(D)}[\frac{\Psi}{B_T}]$$

Hence we arrive at a unique price and it doesn't really matter for the validity of this price that it comes from a model family consisting of incomplete models.

My questions would be:

1. In practice, would one ever calculate the price intervall for an incomplete model? If yes, why?
2. Am I correct that the topic of non-unique prices for incomplete models is a non-issue in practice?

Comment: @Kermittfrog Done

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing your question in more clarity, very nice. +1

Comment: @Kevin 1) True but how does that matter? Just because we use an incomplete model class to model an uncomplete reality we do not actually model reality more accurately since we will eventually use a certain martingale measure to price the derivative anyway. 

2) I am too much of a beginner to assess this. So you are saying most institutions use incomplete model classes?
3) You could choose a certain price within that range according to other criteria 
4) Why can't you do that in complete markets?

Comment: Some random thoughts: 1) The real world is likely incomplete. There are much more states of nature than independent assets. 2) Most pricing models are incomplete (e.g., jumps or other stochastic state variables). 3) Computing price intervals isn't enough for trading. You can't tell your customer who wants to trade an asset that it costs somewhere between £1 and £2. 4) In incomplete markets, you can choose your hedging strategies to minimise transaction costs, or errors from Delta hedges etc. 5) For portfolio optimisation, you'd also have to maximise over all equivalent martingale measures.

Comment: 5) you could do the same with complete models by maximizing over all martingale measures that imply observed prices in form of a constrained optimization

It probably all just comes down to incomplete models being more complex and better suited to model reality. I just thought that incompleteness was somehow bad.

Comment: 1) I didn't mean to say incomplete models are better because the real world is incomplete. That thought would be wrong. I was just giving some background information. 2) Yes, popular models that are used in practise such as LSV or SVJJ models are incomplete (you can artificially complete some of them, e.g., endow the Heston model with an asset whose value depends on volatility). 3) You shouldn't just arbitrarily choose a price in that price interval. Arbitrary decisions are almost never optimal. Because markets are incomplete, you can't price by means of replication….

Comment: … You could find a unique and optimal price by means of minimum variance hedging. 4) In a complete market, you can only really price by no-arbitrage and replication. These prices are unique. Only in incomplete markets, you have to be more creative. 5) Thus, portfolio optimisation in complete markets only needs to deal with the unique pricing measure and can thus concentrate on optimising over the asset allocation. Bottom line: incompleteness is neither “good” nor “bad”. It arguably makes your life more complicated and interesting though.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the Input! I am still not understanding the point 4) and 5). As  I explictated in my original question, the way I am understanding the typical calibration and pricing pipeline, you'll get a unique price even for incomplete models without being more creative. You can of course choose the martingale measure not only based on how much it implies market prices but also based on hedging costs, utility, risk etc. But it seems to me that you can also do this in the complete case.

Comment: In a complete market, you can't choose an EMM based on hedging, costs, utility functions or risks because there is only one unique EMM. There's nothing to choose from. Market prices of options imply the risk-neutral distribution for one maturity. That’s right. European vanilla options can be priced from market prices in a model-free fashion (it's almost like fancy interpolation). Completeness doesn't matter here. But if you price more exotic structures (American options, barrier options etc.), then you can't obtain their prices from market prices for vanillas. You need a model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129195/discussion-between-roman27-and-kevin).